# How to properly deal with merges when doing a GIT PULL within Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I can't make GIT for TFS properly work within Visual Studio when dealing with merges. Basically every merge operations that occurs when I pull the last version of the code is a nightmare.

I'm specifically talking about merges that occur **when pulling someone's else code from the same branch** (i.e. I'm **not** talking about scenarios involving multiple branches).

I'm also specifically talking about **the built-in GIT plugin of Visual Studio**, so please do not suggest to execute command line commands that I'm aware of (such as rebase) if there is another solution from within the IDE (*"you can't"* would be a valid answer, though).

Here's how to reproduce the issue:

- there are two developers, A and B, working on the same branch
- developer A pushes some commit that modifies files F1 and F2
- developer B modifies files F1 and F3
- developer B commits modifications on F1 and F3
- developer B does a pull: Visual Studio detects a conflict on file F1 (which is expected)
- developer B resolves the conflict on F1

**Now here's the issue: all files F1, F2 and F3 are in the *modified* state for B. Why?** Developer B only modified files F1 and F3. **I don't see a valid reason for F2 to be in the *modified* state**, because B did not modify it.

I understand that *locally* the F2 file is not the same as before the pull, but the problem is that B basically can't review his changes on F1 and F3 before pushing, because everyone else's work (in the simplified case above, on F2) also appears in his list of changes.

In our real world scenarios, there are multiple developers working on the same branch, and every merge is a *major failure* in the branch history: Visual Studio basically shows a bunch of 50-or-so modified files for every merge (when the developer only modified 1 or 2 files).

This issue *always* occurs with an up-to-date Visual Studio 2013. Visual Studio 2015 seems clever enough to *not* show F2 as modified, *but not always*.

How to fix this behavior? Currently GIT is a PITA to use within Visual Studio because of that.

---

EDIT:

Here's a visual example. On the left, the history as shown within VS 2013: plenty of modified files. On the right, the very same history (same repository, same machine, same commit...etc.) as shown within VS 2015. Obviously VS 2015 shows something different and slightly better (I only see my changes). Do note this doesn't *always* work that way, sometimes VS 2015 shows files I didn't modify, just like VS 2013 does.

This question was about this behavior when *I'm about to push the result of a merge*, but it's exactly the same when I simply view the history of a old merge, as shown below:

[image]

The questions are:

- is this a bug?
- if not, is this documented?
- in any case, how am I supposed to work with GIT, especially with VS 2013, in regards to the inconsistency as shown above?

Comment: So developer B has modified F1 and F3, but not pushed to the remote branch, correct?

Comment: @TriskalJM Yes that's it

Comment: Generally you do not look at an uncommitted merge to try to determine how two branches differ.  You would generally compare the branch to the upstream branch after you have completed and committed the merge.  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 and http://www.gitforvisualstudio.com/ may help elucidate some of these concepts.

Comment: One small advice. Learn how to use git bash. That way you will always be able to use git. Now you are wokring in visual studios, in a few years you might be working in Webstorm or Eclipse or what have you.. Learning each individual integrated git tool would be troublesome so I really recommend learning the generic git tools avalible.

Comment: @Edvin Well I've used Visual Studio for more than 10 years now, and I've never done any basic source-control-related task outside of VS (except for file diff). I honestly don't want to start now because of GIT. If there is no solution for my simple problem, either GIT or VS is broken.

Comment: If that is how you feel then I truly hope you find a solution to your problem :) But learning git bash is not hard at all. There is sooo much documentation and tutorials for every possible scenario so I would still recommend it. Best regards, Edvin

Comment: @Edvin I'm sure there are some good documentation out there, but using the command line for such tasks is currently (and I hope won't ever be) part of my daily workflow. I know Microsoft tries to push GIT because of the current hype about open source and all, but that's not how I'm used to work with Visual Studio :) Again, "_you can't, do use the command line_" would be a valid answer if the GIT integration inside Visual Studio is broken, but I sincerely hope it's not (it would be very disappointing).

Comment: You've added a bounty to this, but you haven't explained _what the problem is_.  This is by-design.  Git (on the command-line _and_ in Visual Studio) show you all the files that were affected by a merge, not _only_ the conflicts.  It's not clear what you want or expect to be different.  Do you want an explanation of why this occurs?  Do you want links to training to better understand how to use the Git tooling in VS?

Comment: @EdwardThomson The problem is: VS 2013 and 2015 behave inconsistently. Both don't work the same, and VS 2015 doesn't always shows the same behavior. So the questions are: is this a bug, is this documented, how do work with this inconsistency.

Comment: @ken2k: If `F2` isn't showing up in the changes page in 2015, then that's a bug.  If `F2` was changed in the branch being merged - _even if it's not conflicting_ then it will show in the changes page.  It will _not_ show up in the Team Explorer _Conflicts_ page, though, which is new in 2015, and which is the default view that opens up when you have a merge conflict.  Is this the difference that you're seeing?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I added a screenshot, hopefully it'll be clearer

Comment: Thanks @ken2k - that's helpful.  It wasn't clear that you were talking about the Commit Details view, I read your issue as if you were looking at the Changes page _before you commit_.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I took a screenshot of an old merge because I can't commit stuff on GIT right now, but it's exactly the same _before I commit_. The _Changes_ window you can see here would be exactly the same _before the commit_, i.e. no changes shown on VS 2015 (as I would expect because it's not _my_ changes), plenty of changes shown on VS 2013 (changes made by other people on other files, in case I had to merge).

Answer (score 2):

You only need to understand how git works.

When you say:

> developer B does a pull: Visual Studio detects a conflict on file F1 (which is expected)

That's where you're wrong. Git detects conflicts and can therefore not perform the merge. (Even if you are merging from the "same" branch, what git is doing is create a merge commit to tape these too branches together).

When this happens, git shows you all the differences brought by both branches. You can *git add* (or whatever it's called in visual studio) all files without conflict, they will be part of the "merge commit".

The only thing you need to do is fix the conflicts where they are marked and let the rest but as is and create the merge commit.

**To summarize**, when a merge fails, you get to see both *changes* and *conflicts*. Just focus on fixing the *conflicts* and let the regular *changes* be as they are.

Comment: My question was probably not clear. I understand developer B needs to fix the conflicts _before_ being able to merge. The merge process itself is not an issue to me. The actual issue is specifically related to the _changes_ window of Visual Studio (as well as the _History_ window) that shows both files modified by B (either by fixing a conflict (F1) or other files (F3)) BUT ALSO files modified by other developers (F1).

Comment: @ken2k well, yeah, _changes_ in git terms would include F2 being modified by the other developer on the team.

Comment: @TriskalJM Okay, but why are those changes (made by someone else) displayed within the "included changes" window of developer B? Developer B _can't review_ its own changes before pushing the result of the merge because he won't be able to differentiate what he actually modified from what other people modified.

Comment: I'd suspect it's because the git plugin is calling git commands under the hood, and the pull command does create a _change_ in git terms.

Comment: @TriskalJM I think that's indeed how it works under the hood. So the question is: how do people use GIT within Visual Studio? This issue really is a no-go for me. I can't imagine that nobody ever get the same issue before (and maybe a solution).

Comment: Not sure, but I think the answer is that most git workflows assume different branches for different team members.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Visual studio 2013 with Git & it works perfectly fine for the scenario you mentioned above.

What I might suggest is to check if there is some difference in User Settings of those developers. Any change in Line endings, tab space or Using Ctrl+K+F(formatting shortcut) can be issue.

What I suggest to uninstall any custom plugin, tool apart from native VS support, update Visual Studio to latest patch.

If issues still persists, try importing same User setting across all devs in Visual Studio. Refer :[How to: Share Settings Between Computers or Visual Studio Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/1x6229t8(v=vs.90).aspx)

Tools => Import & Export Settings.. =>

[image]

Next=>
[image]

Export this setting & import to all other users so that all users are having same settings.

Different plugins like git extensions, tortoise git or any other custom git extension can play with line endings or default tab spaces that results in changes detected in almost all changed files by any developer.

Comment: The behavior described in the question occurred on a freshly installed up-to-date VS 2013

Comment: Then I will suggest to make sure no other plugin for git is installed & use same VS settings across all devs.